# Rundll32 example, how to get SourceSafe version

Tags: visual-studio, dll, rundll32.exe

I've first asked this question on StackOverflow, but seen the very little attention and the relevance for SuperUser, I've decided to deleted the StackOverflow post and ask it again here:

*Background:*

I've just installed Microsoft SourceSafe and I'm trying to integrate it with my Visual Studio installation. Therefore I'm following the guidelines, mentioned in [this URL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/how-to-install-a-source-control-plug-in). It seems not to be working, and I'm trying to find what to do:
There is the following quote:

> First, Visual Studio checks the value returned by calling the
>   SccGetVersion. It must be greater than or equal to 1.2.

The mentioned function `SccGetVersion` is a part of the DLL ssscc.dll, mentioned elsewhere in the mentioned URL, so in order to verify if the version is 1.2 indeed, I try to get that version myself, by running the mentioned function within that dll. This seems not to be working:

*Situation:*

```
Prompt>rundll32 ssscc.dll,SccGetVersion
```

I'm in the right directory, and there is no error message, so I'm doing something right, but I don't get a result, so I must be doing something wrong?

Does anybody have an idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of SourceSafe are you actually using [there seems to be a difference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181082(v=vs.80).aspx)? Why would you expect to arbitrarily call a function and get that return?

Comment: I've installed Visual SourceSafe Explorer - 32-bit, version 8.0.50727.42. As it is mentioned in the quote, Visual Studio checks the version returned by the mentioned function, but as I don't see the expected behavior in Visual Studio, I decided to check the version manually, and I hoped that, running `rundll32` I could achieve this. Is this wrong?